# Custom User Registration with association table using .Net Identity

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, asp.net-identity, user-registration

I am using .Net Identity for user manangement.  Registration of a user includes saving other details such as address.  The addresses are saved in a Address table and I have an association table called AddressBook which has mapping of User and Address along with some other details.  Since AddressBook table contains other columns, I cannot use many-many relationship, rather need two 1-Many relationship with the UserAdddress table.

```
public class AspNetUser
{

public string Id { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<AddressBook> AddressBooks { get; set; }

}
public partial class Address
{
    public long AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AddressBook> AddressBooks { get; set; }
}

public partial class AddressBook
{
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
public long AddressId { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]
public string UserId { get; set; }

public int? AddressTypeId { get; set; }
public bool? IsDefault { get; set; }
public string Firstname { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make use of the Register method in the Account Controller which is part of .Net Identity.  My Application User and Application DbContext and  look like this(Note: I have 2 contexts):

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    { 
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            AddressBooks = new HashSet<AddressBook>();
        }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public virtual ICollection<AddressBook> AddressBooks { get; set; }
    }
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
 {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers").HasKey(k => k.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasKey(k => k.AddressId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AddressBook>().HasKey(k =>
            new
            {
                k.UserId,
                k.AddressId,

            }
        );
             modelBuilder.Entity<AddressBook>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Address)
            .WithMany(t => t.AddressBooks)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.AddressId);

             modelBuilder.Entity<AddressBook>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.AspNetUser)
            .WithMany(t => t.AddressBooks)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.UserId);
    }  
}
```

In the Account Controller, I want to pass Address Info as well as AddressBook info when I register by calling await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,password );

I tried the following and it didn't work:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {

            UserName = "NewUser5" ,
            Email = "a9@snapon.com"


    };

  var addr = new Address { Address1 = "5505" , City = "City A" , Zip = "91334" };
var addressBook = new AddressBook() {Address = addr,   UserId = 
user.Id,Firstname = "ContactFName" , LastName = "ConatactLName" , 
AddressTypeId = 1, IsDefault = true };

user.AddressBooks.Add(addressBook);

IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password );
```

It gives me the error Invalid column name ApplicationUser_Id.  I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Is it even possible to save in a two 1-M relationship using Identity?

Answer (score 1):

This is a longshot, but try calling the following instead.

```
UserManager<AspNetUser>.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

It works for me in .net core.

Comment: For me AspNetUser not found in any contexts... What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Install AspNetIdentity NuGet package.